How to adjust the component diagram in this case for better readability?
I have created a Python code where a main algorithm uses three different modules (.py) after importing them.
To illustrate and describe it I have create the following component diagram?

Could it be improved for better description and readability?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your diagram is ok, if you just want to show that the main module is wired with the three others. But it does not give any details on how the modules are assembled, and misleads to think that the three auxiliary modules all use the same interface.
If you want to keep it very general like that, it would be sufficient to show a use dependency of the main algorithm to the 3 used modules.
But it may be more interesting to show the "interfaces" used by the main module, and the interface it exposes to other modules. This helps to give a better underdog how the modules are wired together. See here here how to do it, using the lollipops (exposed interface) and the sockets (consumed interfaces).

no interface was used, why would I use interface in UML connections

could I add to the diagram the important Python libraries used in each module ?

The interface is a quite general term here, to describe the contract that is offered/required by components. It can be some key APIs you rely on. But if one of the component is a library it may indeed clutter the diagram.  The python libraries are from a design perspective components like any others (and the python library doc documents the "contracts" behind each function/class). You may also add them to the diagram. But the question is: what does it add as value to your diagram.  The use of standard libraries (e.g. for i/o) are often an implementation constraint related to the choice of ...

... the implementation language, and not necessarily a key design choice. Moreover, you need to keep the diagram up to date much more frequently. I'd advise not to, unless for very special libraries for which there could be alternatives on the market, or unless you want to use the component diagram more to document a specific implementation rather than the overarching design.

If it is more for documenting the implementation, you may consider using pyreverse. Unfortunately it doesn't generate a component diagram, but it can produce a "package" diagram, where package represent modules, and it is able depending on the options to also show standard library dependencies. It may not be exactly what you want but has the advantage of automation: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyreverse.html

using pyreverse doesn't seem to be plotting the relation between the components, I just got one big component with all the attributes and method inside but no relationships with the imported scripts, weird!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@PatrickSchulz It's a little tricky because pyreverse is quite sensitive to the location you're calling it and the options and the paths in configuration vs filename. Anyway it doesn't change the answer but is worth to know for automation.  There are some q&a on StackOverflow and the authors of the tool also are around there and comment. But it would need some minimal code to reproduce.
